# labels and controls not correctly aligned

Tags: html, css

I am designing an HTML template using bootstrap 4.3 and having issues with my column alignments. I am new to boostrap hence finding it difficult to align. If you notice some of the text in the columns wrap and the columns following the controls are not currently aligned since the width of the first column varies. I need to keep the width of the first column consistent so that the controls following that are aligned correctly from top to bottom. I have applied col-md-1 for the labels. Increasing it to col-md2 makes it even longer. Could some body help me with that

See the screenshot below

[image]

Html

```
<style>
    .desc-header {
        background-color: #FAE7D6;
        color: black
    }

    .header {
        width: 8%;
    }


    .panel-heading {
        color: white;
        background-color: #F59850;
        border-color: #ddd;
    }

    .scrollClass {
        height: 800px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
        overflow-x: hidden;


    }
</style>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header panel-heading">
        <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; ">Firm Details</span>
        <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:10px;">
            <label class="btn btn-primary" [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': EditMode, 'btn-default': !EditMode }"><input
                    type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="EditMode" class="hidden">Edit Mode</label>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

        <form [formGroup]="frmFirm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div *ngIf="FirmDetails && FirmDetails.Firm" class="card-body scrollClass" style="width:100%">

                <div  class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputName" class="col-md-1 col-form-label modal-label header">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Firm.NAME}}</div>
                        <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                            formControlName="firmName" />
                    </div>


                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputTitle" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Short Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Firm.SHORT_NAME}}</div>
                        <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                            formControlName="shortName" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Alternate Name</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Firm.ALTERNATE_NAME}}</div>
                        <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control"
                            formControlName="alternateName" />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Date Founded</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{dateFoundedDate}}</div>
                        <kendo-datepicker *ngIf="EditMode" [format]="'MMMM yyyy'" formControlName="dateFounded">
                        </kendo-datepicker>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Intralinks Connections</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="inputEmail">User Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Password</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div formArrayName="intraLinks"
                            *ngFor="let item of frmFirm.get('intraLinks').controls; let i = index; let last = last">
                            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input style="width:100%" formControlName="intraUsername"
                                            placeholder="User Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input style="width:100%" formControlName="intraPassword"
                                            placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div *ngIf="EditMode" class="col-md-3">
                                        <button class="fa fa-trash" (click)="removeCredentials()"></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="EditMode">
                            <button (click)="addCredentials()">Add Credentials</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Key Contact</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div *ngIf="!EditMode && FirmDetails.People">{{FirmDetails.KeyContact.Name}}</div>
                        <kendo-dropdownlist *ngIf="EditMode" style="width:100%" [data]="FirmDetails.People"
                            formControlName="People" [defaultItem]="FirmDetails.KeyContact.Name" [valuePrimitive]="true"
                            [filterable]="false" textField="Name" valueField="ID"></kendo-dropdownlist>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Websites</label>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Website URL</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="inputEmail">User Name</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <label for="inputEmail">Password</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div formArrayName="websites"
                            *ngFor="let item of frmFirm.get('websites').controls; let i = index; let last = last">
                            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input style="width:100%" formControlName="websiteUrl"
                                            placeholder="Website Url">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input style="width:100%" formControlName="username" placeholder="User Name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <input style="width:100%" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password">
                                    </div>
                                    <div *ngIf="EditMode" class="col-md-3">
                                        <button (click)="removeWebsite()">Remove Website</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="EditMode">
                            <button (click)="addWebsite()">Add Website</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <!-- <label for="inputEmail" class="col-md-1 col-form-label header">Addresses</label> -->
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <!-- <div *ngIf="!EditMode">{{FirmDetails.Firm.Addresses}}</div> -->
                        <!-- <input *ngIf="EditMode" kendoTextBox [readonly]="false" class="form-control" /> -->

                        <div formArrayName="addressess"
                            *ngFor="let item of frmFirm.get('addressess').controls; let i = index;">

                            <div [formGroupName]="i">

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label header" attr.for="{{'streetId' + i}}">Street
                                        1</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="{{'streetId' + i}}" type="text"
                                            placeholder="Street address (required)" formControlName="street">

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label header" attr.for="{{'line2Id' + i}}">Line
                                        2</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="{{'line2Id' + i}}" type="text"
                                            placeholder="Street address (second line)" formControlName="line2">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label header" attr.for="{{'line3Id' + i}}">Line
                                        3</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="{{'line3Id' + i}}" type="text"
                                            placeholder="Street address (third line)" formControlName="line3">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row ">
                                    <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label header" attr.for="{{'cityId' + i}}">City, Zip
                                        Code</label>
                                    <!-- <div *ngIf="!EditMode && FirmDetails.People">{{FirmDetails.Addresses}}</div> -->
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <kendo-dropdownlist style="width:100%" [data]="cities" [defaultItem]=""
                                            [valuePrimitive]="true" formControlName="city" [defaultItem]=""
                                            [filterable]="true" textField="Name" valueField="Id"></kendo-dropdownlist>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="{{'zipCodeId' + i}}" type="number"
                                            placeholder="Zip Code" formControlName="zipCode">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                        <label class="col-md-1 col-form-label header" attr.for="{{'phoneId' + i}}">Line
                                            3</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-9">
                                            <input class="form-control" id="{{'phoneId' + i}}" type="text"
                                                placeholder="Phone" formControlName="phone">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div *ngIf="EditMode">
                            <button (click)="addAddress()">Add Address</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-top:10px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 30px;">
                        <div class="desc-header">Firm History</div>
                        <div class="divEditor">
                            <ckeditor [editor]="Editor" [id]="'ckFirmHistory'" *ngIf="EditMode"
                                formControlName="firmHistory" style="font-size: 11px;" debounce="500"
                                [config]="EditorConfig">
                            </ckeditor>
                            <div style="padding: 10px" *ngIf="!EditMode" [innerHTML]="FirmDetails.Firm.HISTORY_HTML">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>



            </div>
            <div class="btn-toolbar" style="padding-top:40px;">
                <span> <button class="btn btn-default btn mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>
                        Download Template
                    </button>
                </span>
                <span> <button class="btn btn-default btn mr-3">
                        <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i>
                        Upload Template Data
                    </button>
                </span>
                <span *ngIf="EditMode"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                        (click)="saveManager()">Save</button>

                </span>
                <span><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all btn mr-3"
                        (click)="cancelManager">Cancel</button>
                </span>
                <span><button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-primary btn-view-all"
                        (click)="deleteManager()">Delete</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to change the `col-md-1` class to the `col-md-2` and apply the `col-lg-1` class to all your label elements. `col-lg-` applies for devices more than 992px. It should help you.

Comment: So currently my label is having class="col-md-1", Are you saying apply class="col-md-2  col-lg-1 "

Comment: Yes, that's right. You also can try add the `col-sm-` class to use it on phones with width less than 762px if you get the incorrect rendering on smaller devices.